# Linphone failure: There is no object pool created in thread

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, voip, linphone

If I let my application sit for a while or after a couple calls I get the following crash on linphone:

> 2016-11-09 09:21:17:372 ortp-message-Listening point [0x1740fe480] on
>   [sip:0.0.0.0:5060;transport=UDP] destroyed 2016-11-09 09:21:17:372
>   ortp-message-Listening point [0x1740fe500] on
>   [sip:0.0.0.0:5060;transport=TCP] destroyed 2016-11-09 09:21:17:373
>   ortp-message-Listening point [0x1740fe580] on
>   [sip:0.0.0.0:49391;transport=TLS] destroyed 2016-11-09 09:21:17:373
>   ortp-message-sal_unlisten_ports done 2016-11-09 09:21:17:373
>   ortp-message-http provider destroyed. 2016-11-09 09:21:17:373
>   ortp-message-stack [0x17434dd60] destroyed. 2016-11-09 09:32:44.566120
>   Setec[249:9352] [MC] Invalidating cache 2016-11-09 09:32:44.567110
>   Setec[249:7759] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
>   SetupCalls 2016-11-09 09:45:36.743273 Setec[249:10714] MakeCall..
>   2016-11-09 09:45:36.743842 Setec[249:10714] identity:
>   sip:5612954779@phoneserverhere 2016-11-09 09:45:36:744
>   ortp-warning-There is no object pool created in thread [6140047360].
>   Use belle_sip_object_pool_push() to create one. Unowned objects not
>   unref'd will be leaked.

The code I am using is:

```
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        NSLog("MakeCall..")

    guard let _ = self.setIdentify() else {
        print("no identity in makeCall")
        return
    }

    linphone_core_invite(lc, numberToCall)
    self.mainLoop(sec: 5)
    self.shutdown()
    }
```

and it gets caught in the guard.

Comment: You say "crash" but what you posted isn't a crash report.

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score -1):

Select "Enable Bitcode" = Yes from Build Settings.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? Also, consider reading up on some [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).